# Showing bulleted list for cell content

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have multiple lines to be displayed inside a cell.

I was able to adjust the font size and cell height and wrap the contents inside the cell but I want to display the contents as a bulleted list (each line as a list item) inside the cell.

But I have no clue how to proceed with it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything ready in the sdk for this, but you can create your custom cell to do it.
You can than implement something like -(void)addRow:(NSString)text which create an UILabel and add it to the cell view (with a little imageview to the left if you want it, or maybe just a special character in the string of the UILabel). You will have to "think" some way to know where to place the just created label, something like a global var inside your custom cell that contain the last placed label origins.

Something like:

```
//global var
CGPoint lastPoint;

-(void)addRow {
//creation of the label
...
//update last point
last point.y += //here the expected height of your labels
}
```

You will also have to update the cell size each row added.

Edit: the Unicode char you may be interested in is "\u2022"